# debian-tor vs User

Tags: bridge, debian

Switch from root to user = su usrname >Password.
The problems start when I try and `su` to `debian-tor`. First I get a query for a password which it doesn't have. So I make a pass for `debian-tor` and enter it when I `su` to `debian-tor`. I enter `whoami` and the response is: `user` and not `debian-tor`. With or without a password it doesn't work. Secondly, if I su debian-tor >passwrd - sudo -u debian-tor nyx it produces a page and a half of pure gibberish. Sudo -i to root and enter nyx, it operates perfectly; and yes I understand I shouldn't run nyx as root.

How do I become `debian-tor` so I can operate my bridge correctly?

Comment: Yours look different because you changed the setting of debian-tor as you mentioned in your post.

Answer (score 1):

debian-tor is an service account (group) created by Tor during installation. It has it's shell acces set to `/bin/flase` which means you'll be logged out immediately when trying to login using it.

You can check it by typing `sudo cat /etc/passwd | grep debian-tor`

So what you have to do is to add the default user, for example ubuntu in Ubuntu operating system, to the `debian-tor` group. You can do it by typing `sudo usermod -a -G debian-tor your_default_user`

After this you'll have to edit the torrc file and add the line `CookieAuthFileGroupReadable 1` and `DataDirectoryGroupReadable 1`in the file.

Then you'll have to restart tor, log out and login again (because you just change the user's group setting).

After that, if you type in `nyx` you should able to start nyx as a non-root user.

It took a while for me to figure it out as well. Hope this help.

Comment: cat /etc/passwd | grep debian-tor =
tor:x:112:116::/var/lib/tor:/home/debian-tor

Comment: the above can't be correct

Comment: How about `getent group debian-tor`

Comment: I saw your question on the tor-relay mailing list as well.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's an obvious **flaw** in Debian - an empty users. To solve this I suggest the next sequence I'm using myself for more than a decade to mend this kind of things:

1. Make a `nossh` user group and make a sshd config change to make sure that no user belonging to it can do a ssh login
2. Add the desired user like `debian-tor`, `tor` e.t.c to this group
3. Change the shell to `/bin/bash` for the user you need to be working properly
4. Make sure that either in Tor/other-service config file it does the setuidgid() call to change to that user or use a SystemD User and Group service directives to make it from the systemd level - anyway the end result will be the same **except** the privileged port binding, keep that in mind